# Measure extension theorem(unique)

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Please give an example of two probability measures $\mu \not = \nu$ on $\cal{F} $= all
subsets of {1, 2, 3, 4} that agree on a collection of sets C with $\sigma(C)=\cal{F}$ .

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know that $\sigma$-finiteness of a pre-measure on a generating algebra guarantees uniqueness of the extended measure?

Comment: @snarski And how does this help?

Comment: @Did It escaped me that these are meant to be probability measures. I thought one way to proceed would be violate conditions for a unique extension, but nowhere does OP mention $C$ has any structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, $C$ should *not* be a $\pi$-system (*do you know why?*). Let me provide some collection $C$ that works and let you find $\mu$ and $\nu$ (there are infinitely many such pairs): $$C=\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,2,3,4\}\}.$$

Comment: why should not be $\pi$-systems?do you mean that C should not be a semi-algebra?

Comment: this is an exercise in durrett.the answer shows a measure similar to yours but not a prob. measure. does it matter?

Comment: Because a well-known result concerns the uniqueness of probability measures with the same restriction to a pi-system generating the full sigma-algebra, that's why...

Comment: I know the thm. that you meaned. but the thm. requires not only the $\pi$-system but also a seqence$A_n\in C$ satisfies $A_n \uparrow \Omega$

Comment: No. What is the *precise statement* of the result you are mentioning?

Comment: http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf page361 thm A.1.5

Comment: Read the statement of the theorem: when $\mu$ and $\nu$ are **probability** measures, do you think the condition involving their finiteness on a sequence may not hold?

Comment: (1)If $A_n$ is selected from $\sigma(C)$ the statement is true obviously ,but now they are selected from C like the example you gave before there is no sequence from {{1 2}{13}}

Comment: (2)Is there sth wrong with this exercise? the answer gave $\mu$ the counting measure. I don't believe it is a prob. measure.

Comment: Who said the A_n should be selected from C? // "The counting measureé should probably be understood as the *normalized* counting measure.

Comment: the thm. I showed you before.$\cal{P}$ in the text is C here.

Comment: Then add the full space to C and be happy.